# When select different options shows different input, but all inputs of all options are required

Tags: javascript, django

I'm working with Django and I made a function that creates a person (employee, student, or worker) and as you can see I created the three different forms on create_person, so on the template, when you select an option on school_role to choose what kind of person you will create, its shows different inputs and select, it depends if you click on student, academic or employee. This is ok, but my problem is that I need to fill all of the inputs and selects on all of the three options to be able to send the form, and I need that you just have to fill one ( employee, academic, or student).

```
def create_person(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonForm(request.POST)
        daysform = AvailableDayForm(request.POST)
        studentForm = StudentForm(request.POST)
        academicForm = AcademicForm(request.POST)
        employeeForm = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and daysform.is_valid():
            data = form.save()
            daysform.save(id=data.id)
            id = data.id
            if(data.school_role==1):
                if studentForm.is_valid():
                    studentForm.save(id = id)
                    messages.success(
                    request=request,
                    message='success'
                    )
                    return redirect('cases:list')
            elif(data.school_role == 2):
                if academicForm.is_valid():
                    academicForm.save(id = id)
                    messages.success(
                    request=request,
                    message='success'
                    )
                    return redirect('cases:list')
            else:
                if employeeForm.is_valid():
                    employeeForm.save(id = id)
                    messages.success(
                    request=request,
                    message='success'
                    )
                    return redirect('cases:list')

              
    else:
        form = PersonForm()
        daysform = AvailableDayForm()
        studentForm = StudentForm()
        academicForm = AcademicForm()
        employeeForm = EmployeeForm()
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'studentForm': studentForm,
            'academicForm': academicForm,
            'employeeForm': employeeForm,
            'daysform': daysform
        }

    return render(request, 'person/create_person.html', context)
```

This is the template create_person.html:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <h1 class="title">New person </h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for non_field_error in form.non_field_errors %}
      <p class="help is-danger">{{ non_field_error }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
      {% for field in form %}
      <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
          <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="label">
            {{field.label}}
          </label>
          {% if field.field.widget.input_type == 'select' %}
            {%if field.name ==  'school_role'%}

            <div class="select">
            <select onchange="yesnoCheck(this);" name = "school_role" required>
                <option value="">--------</option>
                <option value="1">Student</option>
                <option value="2">Academic</option>
                <option value="3">Employee</option>
              </select>
        </div>

            <div id="ifStudent" style="display: none;">
                          {% for field in studentForm %}
                    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="label">
                        {{field.label}}
                    </label>
                    {% if field.field.widget.input_type == 'select' %}
                      <div class="select">
                        {{ field }}
                      </div>
                    {% else %}
                      {{ field }}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                      <p class="help is-danger">{{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <div id="ifAcademic" style="display: none;">
              {% for field in academicForm %}
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="label">
            {{field.label}}
        </label>
        {% if field.field.widget.input_type == 'select' %}
          <div class="select">
            {{ field }}
          </div>
        {% else %}
          {{ field }}
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p class="help is-danger">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
            </div>


            <div id="ifWorker" style="display: none;">
              {% for field in employeeForm %}
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="label">
            {{field.label}}
        </label>
        {% if field.field.widget.input_type == 'select' %}
          <div class="select">
            {{ field }}
          </div>
        {% else %}
          {{ field }}
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p class="help is-danger">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
            </div>

            {%else%}
            <div class="select">
              {{ field }}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
          {% else %}
          {{ field }}
          {% endif %}
          {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p class="help is-danger">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

And this is my script.

```
function yesnoCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "1") {
        document.getElementById("ifStudent").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifStudent").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (that.value == "2"){
        document.getElementById("ifAcademic").style.display = "block";
    } else  {
        document.getElementById("ifAcademic").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (that.value == "3"){
        document.getElementById("ifWorker").style.display = "block";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("ifWorker").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of hiding or showing the forms that are all in the page I think you should split the forms. I would create a form with `school_role` and when you submit that form, in the next step you render the form depending on the choice from the first step. If you definitely want it to be in the same page, you can either use htmx or render the form with javascript (which is a bit more work.

Comment: Could you please tell me the idea of how to implement it with javascript?